# Google Tag Manager - DOM Element variable - get text of child element

Tags: google-tag-manager

Just learning GTM. I'm wanting to use GTM to get the text of an element using the DOM Element variable I have named as 'specimen'.  That variable is currently set to the CSS selector `specimen`.

The trigger is a 'Click - All Elements' type set to the class `specimen_record_thumbnail`.

As can be seen in the DOM below, the `specimen` selector needs to be confined to the parent of the clicked trigger, which is `specimen_record_container`, as the page will contain a number of those structures/classes.

How should I define the CSS selector in the DOM Element variable to get the text of the `specimen` selector for the sibling `specimen_record_thumbnail` ?

```
<div class="specimen_record_container">
        <img class="specimen_record_thumbnail" data-specimen="374" src="specimen_media/374/specimen_pk_374_20082014_123312_thumbnail.jpg" border="0">
        <div class="diagnosis" title="<p>Adrenal gland</p>" rel="tooltip">Diagnosis</div>
        <span class="specimen"> T93.M8006<sup>5</sup></span>
    </div>
```

Also, perhaps a custom JavaScript variable might be better...

Any help or advice appreciated!

**Update - Working solution:** Thanks to Eike Pierstorff

This code goes into a GTM Custom JavaScript variable to get the text of the second last child for the parent container, which is then set as the label for a Universal Analytics Tag:

```
function () { return {{Click Element}}.parentNode.lastChild.previousSibling.innerText }
```

Comment: Totally untested so not an answer, but something like {{Click Element}}.parentNode.lastChild might work (if the "specimen" is guaranteed to be the last child of the specimen_record_container" element).

Comment: Thanks, tried that but in GA, I get the event label "[object HTMLImageElement].parentNode.lastChild"  also tried appending innerHTML...

Comment: You would need to put this in a custom js variable (as an anonymous function that returns {{Click Element}}.parentNode.lastChild.innerText).

Comment: Thanks!  That works.  Actually, as it turns out, the markup for the DOM in the OP was incorrect.  It's the second last child that I'm wanting to capture.  I tried parentNode.nth-child(2) but looks like you can't use nth-child like that.  So I used function () {
  return {{Click Element}}.parentNode.lastChild.previousSibling.innerText
}    @Eike Pierstorff put your answer in and I'll accept it!